# Jest - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with @nestjs/axios

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I'm just trying to run some integration tests on a nestjs app, but I'm getting the following error:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I spent a lot of time on this problem that should be easy to fix but I can't deal with it.
This problem occurs with `@nestjs/axios` lib which uses ESM instead of CommonJs. After doing some research, I saw that theoretically I should run the tests with this command:

`yarn node --experimental-vm-modules $(yarn bin jest)`

But nothing i do works
I also don't understand why this file is being matched since it is in node_modules
Can someone help me?

My Jest config:

```
"jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "json",
            "ts"
        ],
        "rootDir": "",
        "preset": "ts-jest",
        "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "globalSetup": "<rootDir>/tests/jest.setup.ts",
        "globalTeardown": "<rootDir>/tests/jest.teardown.ts"
    }
```

My versions:

```
"@nestjs/axios": "^1.0.1",
"@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
"jest": "^26.0.0",
"ts-jest": "^26.5.5",
"typescript": "^4.2.3"
```

I've already tried putting node_modules (which is already jest's default behavior) in the `transformIgnorePatterns` setting, but it's not working.

The lib I'm having this error is an internal lib (node_modules/@bank/auth/node_modules/@nestjs/axios/node_modules/axios/index.js:1), could it be the reason for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with jest and ts-jest seeing the library as an ESM module due to how the package.json is set up. You should be able to add this to your jest config and have no issues.

```s
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^axios$': require.resolve('axios'),
},
```

This should force `jest` to resolve the library correctly from `node_modules`

Comment: this seems to do the trick!

Comment: I got EJSONPARSE error If I use this syntax

Comment: @monkeyUser you probably have a `.json` file for the jest config, or you have the jest config inside the `package.json`. To use the above it needs to be a `js` or a `ts` file

Answer (score 0):

You must update the version of jest

```
"@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
"jest": "29.7.0",
"ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
```